# .save() on existing model causes POST instead of PUT

Tags: backbone.js

I'm having some trouble saving changes to individual models in a collection.  Models that have been loaded (via a collection .reset()) are issuing a POST (as if they were new) instead of the expected PUT.

Here's the approach I'm taking:

**AppView**

- Loads the child collection via this.model.childcollection.reset(JSON DATA FROM SERVER);
- In it's render function, creates a new childview for each item in the collection and renders it:

  ```
  render: function() {
          var el = this.el;
          this.model.childcollection.forEach(function(s) {
          var view = new ChildView({ model: s });
          el.append(view.render().el);
      });
      return this;
  },
  ```

**ChildView**

- In one of its events it is changing some values of the underlying model and calling save:

  ```
  this.model.set(
          {
              ValueA: somevalue,
              ValueB: somevalue
          },
          {
              error: function() {
                  console.log("Error saving model");
              },
              success: function() {
                  console.log("Model change saved");
              }
          });
      this.model.save();
  ```

Observations:

- POST (with no child id) is called instead of PUT (with child Id)
- Child elements have Ids set

Can anyone tell me why this may be happening?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

backbone used the `.id` property (not attribute) of the model to determine whether it should put or post, as shown here in the source code: https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L344-346

if it's doing a post when saving an existing model, this means the `.id` property wasn't loaded correctly. even if a call to `model.get("id")` returns the right result, a call to `model.id` must return the right result for it to know that this is not a new model.

be sure you're model's id attribute is called `id`, or if it's not, be sure to set the `idAttribute` on your model:

```
MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  idAttribute: "myCustomId"
});
```

Comment: Thanks - that appears to have been the problem - the 'Id' property name on the server side model was capitalised. Changing it to lowercase seems to have fixed it.

Comment: Alternatively, you could have changed the field name that Backbone considers the ID field by using the `idAttribute` option when extending Backbone.Model.