# backbonejs POSTinstead of PUT on save

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm having an issue when I try to update a task model to the database. It acts as if its a new model. I also get an error after the save that may be related? error and code are below. Is there any additional information needed?

I looked at this [question related to my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473057/save-on-existing-model-causes-post-instead-of-put) but I have ensured that im using the id attribute.

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (obj) { return new wrapper(obj); } has no method 'has'
_.extend.setbackbone.js:246
_.extend.save.options.successbackbone.js:308
jQuery.Callbacks.firejquery.js:1046
jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWithjquery.js:1164
donejquery.js:7399
jQuery.ajaxTransport.send.callback
```

Code:

```
Update: function(id) {
            console.log('Updating task');
            this.task = this.taskList.get(id);
            var new_task_name = prompt("enter new name for " + this.task.get("name"),"Default...");
            console.log('saving task ' + this.task.id +': '+ this.task.get("name") + ' isNew? -' + this.task.isNew());
            this.task.save({
                name: new_task_name
            });
            console.log('task saved ' + this.task.id +': '+ this.task.get("name") + ' isNew? -' + this.task.isNew());

            this.taskView = new TaskView({
                model: this.task
            });
            this.taskView.render();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue... The wording is swapped in the [Codeigniter restful API](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver) I'm using. They handle POST as update and PUT as new.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your error is. If the model has an id set then isNew() should return false. Check the 'idAttribute' on your model and that this value is set on the model.

One issue that you do have is that the save() method is asynchronous. If you want to render the TaskView when the task is saved you should add a success handler (and an error handler if it failed) e.g.

```
var me = this;
this.task.save({
    name: new_task_name
}, {
    success: function(task, response) {
        console.log('task saved ' + task.id +': '+ task.get("name") + ' isNew? -' + task.isNew());

        me.taskView = new TaskView({
            model: task
        });
        me.taskView.render();
    },
    error: function(model, response) {
        var errorMsg;
        // Response may be string (if failed model validation) or an AJAX response (if failed server side)
        if (_.isString(response))
            errorMsg = response;
        else
            errorMsg = response.responseText;

        // Display error
    }
});
```

Comment: No problem, note in your example the name would be updated in the view correctly however in a more complex example where the server updates other properties this is useful. The error handler should be there regardless in case the save fails.

Comment: yea I just implemented this the other day and changed the view rendering based on callback.