# Backbone doing POST request instead of PUT request

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to set a model's attribute to be something different. When I save the model, Backbone issues a POST request instead of a PUT request.

I read on another Stackoverflow post that Backbone uses a model's id to determine if a model is new or not. When I `console.log(model)`, the model has an id attribute. When I `console.log(model.id)`, it prints out undefined. How come when I do a `console.log(model)`, the model has a id attribute, yet when I do `console.log(model.id)`, I get back undefined?

Which way does Backbone use to determine if a model is new or not? And, how can I fix the problem? I am using backbone-tastypie.

Comment: Does this help? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473057/save-on-existing-model-causes-post-instead-of-put

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you create the model in the first place? The model's id needs to be specified in the model's data. Usually this would be returned in the server response the first time you save a new object. Once the id is set Backbone will save it with PUT instead of POST.

Comment: I created the model through Backbone. It actually does have an id attribute. When I do model.get("id"), I get the valid ID.

Comment: The problem was a timing issue. I had to put the code to get the id within the success callback that got called after a successful fetch.